# Insert and resize a vector of vector

Tags: c++, vector, insert, resize

How to resize a vector of vector containing integer values.

```
std::vector<std::vecotr<int>> MyVector;
int value = 10;

//need to insert values as 2 rows and 3 columns, like
//Myvector[0][0] = value;
//Myvector[0][1] = value;
//Myvector[0][2] = value;
//Myvector[1][0] = value;
//Myvector[1][1] = value;
//Myvector[1][2] = value;

// ......
//here i have to resize the vector size to 4 rows and 5 cols using resize() function.

MyVector.resize(.......); //Hoe is this possible.
```

The first problem is , I have to insert the values as 2 rows and 3 columns. how can I use `push_back` function for this purpose. After that need to resize to the specified size. Since it a vector of vector I am getting worried about this.

Comment: In my code, there is constant size for an array. All the sizes are dynamically calculated, so I prefer to use a vector, instead of dynamic allocated array, for avoiding memory leaks. Since dynamic allocation without proper deallocation causes memory leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of a vector of vectors as a matrix where the member vectors are "rows".

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > MyVector;
    //Create a row:
    std::vector<int> subVector;
    subVector.push_back(1);
    subVector.push_back(2);
    //put the row into the vector:
    MyVector.push_back(subVector);
    //create another row:
    subVector.clear();
    subVector.push_back(3);
    subVector.push_back(4);
    //put the second row into the vector
    MyVector.push_back(subVector);
    //access the first row and add an element to it:
    MyVector[0].push_back(6);
    //access the second row and add an element to it:
    MyVector[1].push_back(6);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can initianize the vector to contain two vectors, representing a row each. Each of these can be initialized to contain 3 elements, representing the columns:

```
std::vector<std::vecotr<int>> MyVector(2, std::vector<int>(3));
```

then you can resize it by pushing back new rows:

```
// add a row
MyVector.push_back(std::vector<int>(3));
```

To add columns, you could push_back to each row, which is better achieved with a helper function

```
void appendColumn(std::vector<int> v);
```

I think this would all be better managed by writing a wrapper class, so you can easily ensure that the dimensions of all the vectors are all consistent with an NxM matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `MyVector` a wrapper class around your `vector` of `vector`. You can define your own resize operation. In this case, I defined it to resize the columns lazily as the vector is accessed.

```
struct MyVector {
  std::vector< std::vector<int> > vec_;
  size_t cols_;
  struct MySubVector {
    const MyVector &outer_;
    std::vector<int> &vec_;
    MySubVector (MyVector &outer, std::vector<int> &vec)
      : outer_(outer), vec_(vec) {}
    int & operator [] (int i) const {
      vec_.resize(outer_.cols_);
      return vec_[i];
    }
  };
  MySubVector operator [] (int i) {
    return MySubVector(*this, vec_[i]);
  }
  void resize (size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    vec_.resize(rows);
    cols_ = cols;
  }
};
```

If you want the `resize` to set a particular value for you on resize, then you will have to iterate on each row and invoke the resize operation, and set the initializer.

```
struct resize_cols {
  size_t cols;
  int val;
  resize_cols (size_t c, int v) : cols(c), val(v) {}
  void operator () (std::vector<int> &vec) const {
    vec.resize(cols, val);
  }
};

void resize (size_t rows, size_t cols, int v) {
  vec_.resize(rows);
  std::for_each(vec_.begin(), vec_.end(), resize_cols(cols, v));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, just use the `resize` function on the outer vector:

```
MyVector.resize( 2, std::vector<int>( 3, value ) );
```

More generally, if you want to resize without changing existing values,
you'll have to loop.